# Viewing pdf file using file browser utility in jstree

Tags: pdf, jstree

I am using jstree to create file management solution,so far i am able to achieve all the requirement except viewing of pdf on clicking a pdf node.can anyone pls guide me if its possible using the filebrowser utility that is shipped along with jstree.

code snippet

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                if(data && data.selected && data.selected.length) {
                    $.get('?operation=get_content&id=' + data.selected.join(':'), function (d) {
                        if(d && typeof d.type !== 'undefined') {
                            $('#data .content').hide();
                            switch(d.type) {
                                case 'text':
                                case 'txt':
                                case 'md':
                                case 'htaccess':
                                case 'log':
                                case 'sql':
                                case 'php':
                                case 'js':
                                case 'json':
                                case 'css':
                                case 'html':
                                    $('#data .code').show();
                                    $('#code').val(d.content);
                                    break;
                                case 'png':
                                case 'jpg':
                                case 'jpeg':
                                case 'bmp':
                                case 'gif':
                                    $('#data .image img').one('load', function () { $(this).css({'marginTop':'-' + $(this).height()/2 + 'px','marginLeft':'-' + $(this).width()/2 + 'px'}); }).attr('src',d.content);
                                    $('#data .image').show();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    $('#data .default').html(d.content).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject

in the DOM:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="bower_components/pdfobject/pdfobject.min.js"></script>
<div class="pdfviewer" id="pdfRenderer"></div>
```

and add:

```
           case 'pdf':
            $('#data .pdfviewer').show();
            var pdf = new PDFObject({
                url: pdfUrl,
                id: "pdfRendered",
                pdfOpenParams: {
                    view: "FitH"
                }
            }).embed("pdfRenderer");
            break;
```

To your tree ;)

hide the element when no pdf is selected:

```
$('#data .pdfviewer').hide();
```